# use static classes in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, static

```
//that access to layer dataaccess. this uses another webapp
public class UsuariosService: IUsuariosService
{
    IUsuarioRepository _repoUsuarios;
    public UsuariosService(IUsuarioRepository repoUsuarios)
    {
        _repoUsuarios = repoUsuarios;
    }
    public UsuariosModel GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(string data)
    {
        var usuario = new UsuariosModel();
        try
        {
            var usr = _repoUsuarios.GetFiltered(x => x.Login.Trim().Equals(data.Trim(),StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)||x.Email.Trim().Equals(data.Trim(),StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefault();
            if (usr == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                usuario.Intentos = usr.Intentos;
                usuario.Email = usr.Email;
                usuario.Login = usr.Login;
                usuario.Nombre = usr.Nombre;                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return usuario;
    }
}

//this is my bussiness layer for WCf
public class UsuariosBO
{
    private static IUsuariosService _usuariosService;
    private UsuariosBO(IUsuariosService usuariosService)
    {
        _usuariosService = usuariosService;
    }

    public static UsuariosModel GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(string data)
    {
        UsuariosModel usuario = new UsuariosModel();
        try
        {
            usuario = _usuariosService.GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(data);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return usuario;

    }
}

//this is my contract layer
public class UsuariosOPContract : IUsuariosOPContract
{
    public UsuarioContract GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(string data)
    {
        UsuarioContract usuario = new UsuarioContract();
        try
        {
            UsuariosModel usr = UsuariosBO.GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(data);
            usuario.Nombre = usr.Nombre;
            return usuario;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IUsuariosOPContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(string data);

}
```

When I run the service, I get the error

> Server stack trace:     en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    en
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     en
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    en
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    en
>   IUsuariosOPContract.GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(String data)    en
>   UsuariosOPContractClient.GetUsuarioByUsernameOrEmail(String data)

Comment: Please, some idea.

Comment: another way to call to static UsuariosBO